# Filter multidimensional input in PHP

Tags: php, html

I create my inputs using the following pattern:

```
<input type="text" name="general[fooBar]">
```

I wanted to do something like this in my PHP code:

```
$request = array(
   'general' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'general')
);
echo $request['general']['fooBar'];
```

But `filter_input` gives me false here. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: try this `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'general', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);`

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying this without `FILTER_DEFAULT`, it works now!

Comment: You're welcome @Karol Hernik , accept the answer for future reference

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the `FILTER_DEFAULT`,

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'general', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```